# How to get AJAX posted JSON in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am following this [flask tutorial](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/python-javascript-communicate-json/) to learn about building an app in Python.

The tutorial (close to the end) talks about how to get a AJAX posted JSON inside python as follows:

HTML code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// setup some JSON to use
var cars = [
    { "make":"Porsche", "model":"911S" },
    { "make":"Mercedes-Benz", "model":"220SE" },
    { "make":"Jaguar","model": "Mark VII" }
];

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("theButton").onclick = doWork;
}

function doWork() {
    // ajax the JSON to the server
    $.post("receiver", cars, function() {

    });
    // stop link reloading the page
    event.preventDefault();
}
</script>
This will send data using AJAX to Python:
<br/><br/>
<a href="" id="theButton">Click Me</a>
```

Python Code:

```
import sys

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, Response
import random, json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def output():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/receiver', methods = ['POST'])
def worker():
    # read json + reply
    data = request.get_json()
    result = ''

    for item in data:
        # loop over every row
        result += str(item['make']) + '\n'

    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When I run the script and click on the button 'Click me' in the browser, I get the `500 Internal Server Error` when I examine the Response in the browser. If I print the data variable, it prints out `None` in the terminal on the click event. I tried the suggestions given in the comments to use `get_json(forced=true)` in Python script and stringify the `'cars'` JSON in HTML file but in vain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you didn't specify the content type of your post request look what is said [in the official documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.get_json):

> By default this function **will return None if the mimetype is not
>   application/json** but this can be overridden by the force parameter.

you need also to serialize you cars object to json object .

you can do something like this :

```
function doWork() {
    // ajax the JSON to the server
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/receiver',
        data: JSON.stringify (cars),
        success: function(data) { alert('data: ' + data); },
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json'
    });
    // stop link reloading the page
    event.preventDefault();
}
```